# Merge two mysql query into one variable

Tags: php

I want to merge two mysql query in one variable. Please help me with this.

Following is my code:

```
$insert="INSERT INTO location set name='$_POST[city]'";
$insert_country="INSERT INTO location_parent set did='$id[id]',parent='$_POST[country]'";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Place them both in one variable? You can put multiple queries in one variable, separated by semi-colons.

Comment: You mean [like this?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Can you please be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for database transactions. I'd fix the fact that your code will never work as written first, though - that's not how you use array variables in a string.

Comment: Hello, I want to to create a new variable which contains these two variables. Something like:
variable C = Variable A + Variable B

Comment: Why do you want that ?

Comment: As i am new to PHP, can you give me its final code please??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I gave you the answer to that in my comment above...

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query doesn't support multiple queries in one statement. You need https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php
Please see the code sample there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
$insert="INSERT INTO location set name='{$_POST[city]}';";
$insert_country="INSERT INTO location_parent set did='{$id[id]}',parent='{$_POST[country]}';";

$multipleQueries = $insert . $insert_country;
```

Note the syntax changes, adding semi-colons to the query strings, etc. You do have to use a database method that supports multiple queries in one variable.